# tensorflow-*.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: tensorflow

More precisely this error happens when trying to install tensorflow following the tensorflow site instructions. Also you may have Conda already installed in your Machine.

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

> tensorflow-0.6.0-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel
> on this platform.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution or workaround is to install via Conda as below. Was able to instal just fine.

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow
```

More discussed on this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1097).